# Is "that were" required in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> He stinks of clothes (that were) forgotten in a laundry basket.

Should there be a "that were" here? Is it optional? Why or why not?

Comment: _That have been_ would be better - but it is optional because the sentence can be understood without it.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for the suggestion. Why *have been* instead of *were*?

Comment: Jus because 'that's how we say it'. _[The] clothes that were forgotten_  sounds as though the clothes have been rediscovered and are known about. _Clothes that have been forgotten_ describes some hypothetical clothes, as referred to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'that were' is not required but optional. The sentence has a subject and verb, and 'forgotten in a laundry basket' modifies clothes. If some grammar rule somewhere says that the original sentence is wrong, I vote to change that rule. Personally, I find the sentence to be more effective without the addition.